# Printing values in different column same row using APACHE POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

gradeList is an ArrayList of strings with the value "80", "81" ... "85"

```
     for(int y = 0; y < gradeList.size(); y++){
        HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow((short) 1);//1
        HSSFCell cell1 =row1.createCell((short) y+1);//2
        cell1.setCellValue("" + gradeList.get(y));//3
        HSSFCellStyle cellStylei = workbook.createCellStyle();//4
        cellStylei.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREEN.index);
        cell1.setCellStyle(cellStylei);//6
     }
```

Output of Code: _, _, _, _, _, 85. intended Output: 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85.

After changing the code to

```
    HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow((short) 1);//1
    HSSFCell cell1;
    for(int y = 0; y < gradeList.size(); y++){

        cell1 = row1.createCell((short) y+1);//2
        cell1.setCellValue("" + gradeList.get(y));//3

    }
    HSSFCellStyle cellStylei = workbook.createCellStyle();//4
    cellStylei.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREEN.index);//5
```

the code prints 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, and 85 as intended but using the previous six line code it only prints 85. Can someone please explain to me why is first one wrong or not working, and if possible also can you please also explain what lines 4,5, and 6 do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that in your first code, line 1, you are creating the same row for each `gradeList` element, so you are overwritten the row created for the element 80, with the one created with the element 81, etc due to that you only have the last one.

If you modify your first code and create a different row for each `gradeList` element, you can see that all the values are added, for example:

```
HSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow((short) y +1);//1
```

In line 4, you are creating the style that you want to apply to your cell:

```
HSSFCellStyle cellStylei = workbook.createCellStyle();//4
```

In line 5, you are adding the foreground fill color  to green

```
cellStylei.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREEN.index);//5
```

In line 6, you are adding the style to your cell

```
cell1.setCellStyle(cellStylei);//6
```

You can find more information about the different styles in following the [link](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html) and some examples in the [Official poi doc](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html)

Hope this can help you.

Thank you